# Explaining the use of "stdin" in the end of fgets() function

Tags: c, function, structure, stdin

I haven't really found any useful and simple information as to what "stdin" does and how it relates to fgets() when used for example like:

```
fgets(car[i].vehicle.brand, sizeof(car[i].vehicle.brand), stdin);
```

Comment: Do you know what `fgets` is expecting as the last parameter?

Comment: @EugeneSh. As I have understood, it takes a parameter a FILE pointer to which it can write to.

Comment: No, it is pointer to the stream to *read* from. So `stdin` is the handle of the **st**andar**d** **in**put stream. Which is your console unless redirected in the shell.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So it is like an imaginary file where the user just "streams" data into it but without saving it somewhere permanently.

Comment: Some functions such as `getchar()` gets its input from `stdin` which is automatically opened already for you. But there isn't a version of `fgets()` which gets its input from `stdin` so you have to specify it. `stdin` is already open.

Comment: Relevant: [What is stdin in C language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719915/what-is-stdin-in-c-language)

Comment: @WeatherVane Alright sure do! Thank you for your help! ^^